# Explcitly constructor invokation

Tags: java, constructor

**[JLS 8.8.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1)** provides the constructor invokation expression template:

```
ExplicitConstructorInvocation:
    NonWildTypeArgumentsopt this ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
    NonWildTypeArgumentsopt super ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
    Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt super ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
```

I tried the last expression `Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt super ( ArgumentListopt ) ;`, but I got compile-time error.

```
public class Main {

    public <T> Main(T a){
        Outer.<Integer> super(); //error: illegal qualifier; Object is not an inner class
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main a = new Main(new Object());
        // printResult();

    }

    class Outer {
        public <T> Outer() {
        };
    }
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/UdrCWT)

What's the right way to use that expression?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bohemian Trying to understand how it works. What's wrong?

Comment: @Bohemian In general, I'm looking for the right example including usage of the later expression.

Comment: @Bohemian You can't provide the example, can you?

Comment: Primaries are used to invoke the constructor of an inner class. Define an inner class for Outer (I suspect called Inner) and then try again.

Comment: @FelixMarcus Coudln't you provide an example in an answer?

Comment: @st. I can probably make you code compile, but I need to understand what you want the code to do. What do you expect the print? How do you expect the generic type to affect the output? Why do you have a generic parameter on your constructors? What is the intention of the code?